# Regex to split on two or more instances of a punctuation mark, and only one or more of the others

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and I am trying to write one (Python flavour) that would allow me to split at every punctuation mark or whitespace, except for the single hyphen (e.g. `9-5`, `Mon-Fri` would not be split) . However, the text that I want to process sometimes contains a sequence of hyphens like `-------------`, used for separating paragraphs or thematically distinct sections of the document. Therefore, I want a  solution that splits on one or more occurrences of every punctuation mark except the hyphen, and that splits on a combination of 2 or more hyphens.

I have tried with the following code:

```
re.split(r"[-{2,}\.,:\s]", mystring)
```

but the `-{2,}` part gets interpreted literally. I have also tried to incorporate it into a group, but again, the parentheses are interpreted literally.
I am aware that I could write a first regex to replace multiple hyphens with the null character, and a second regex that looks at all other whitespace and punctuation marks; however, I am wondering if there is a way to do it in a single step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most things inside of a character class [...] is a literal EXCEPT a hyphen in certain contexts and backslash (and `/` in some regex flavors...). So `[-{2,}\.,:\s]` is matching all literal characters except for `\s`. There are other character class operators referenced [HERE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) such as `^` but most regex metacharacters no longer work inside a character class.

I think you might be looking for alteration:

```
[,.\/]|-{2,}
 ^            add whatever punctuation you want to split on
```

(In Python, without the notion of opening a regex, you can use `/` inside a character class without escaping it: `[,./]|-{2,}`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ft95O/1)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!